# How do I provide content for a general browser? (using the Useragent)

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, browser-detection

So I have some videos that I post to my blog - Be aware, it's kid pictures, and will probably put in in a child induced coma quickly.

I would like to display the HTTP Live streaming version of the video for those on iOS & Macs, but the standard MP4 file for everyone else. So, it would be great to have logic to provide anyone with Safari the m3u8, and everyone else the mp4. Thanks!

As it stands now, I have to provide 2 different players (which looks bad)

```
        <!-- Begin Video.js Responsive Wrapper -->
    <div style='max-width:800px;'>
        <div class='video-wrapper' style='padding-bottom:45.875%;'>

<!-- Begin Video.js -->
<video id="example_video_id_2142731582" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="800" height="367" poster="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/poster.png" controls preload="none" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/1stBikeRide.m3u8" type='video/mp4' />


</video>
<!-- End Video.js -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Video.js Responsive Wrapper -->
    </p>

    <!-- Begin Video.js Responsive Wrapper -->
    <div style='max-width:800px;'>
        <div class='video-wrapper' style='padding-bottom:45.875%;'>

<!-- Begin Video.js -->
<video id="example_video_id_621346600" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="800" height="367" poster="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/poster.png" controls preload="none" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/First%20Bike%20Ride-Wi-Fi%20High.mp4" type='video/mp4' />


</video>
<!-- End Video.js -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Video.js Responsive Wrapper -->
    </p>
```

Comment: Don't do user agent detection, test for the feature you need.

Comment: Yes, I've heard that's the right way of doing it. But how do I go about detecting that? I'm a novice when it comes to web protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `<source>` elements, and the browser will go through the list until it finds a source element that it supports:

```
<video id="example_video_id_621346600" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="800" height="367" poster="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/poster.png" controls preload="none" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/First%20Bike%20Ride-Wi-Fi%20High.m3u8" type='application/x-mpegURL' />
    <source src="http://blog.thetroutmans.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1stBikeRide/First%20Bike%20Ride-Wi-Fi%20High.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Here's a [random blog post](http://designm.ag/tutorials/code-a-mobile-friendly-html5-video-stream-with-multiple-sources/) I stumbled across awhile ago and bookmarked that talks about this a bit more.